# Update from 12.04 to 12.10 interrupted due to lack of space

Tags: upgrade

I have decided to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. I had about 4.1GB space left on /. NOt until the last minute during the install phase did the upgrade manager ask me to make space on my drive. I started the software manager and now I can't get out of it back to continuing the upgrade. It keeps on asking me to repair the package catalog, and has no x bar or button to close it, nor can I alt-tab to the updater window.

I am stuck half way through an upgrade and can't get out. I have been a fan of Ubuntu for years but after today I fear I have lost confidence.... Please someone help.

Comment: Do I just hard reboot. It seems like it is the only option. Someone please help here.....

Comment: OK. So no reply amd I rebooted. It starts to boot. but stops after the ubuntu circle screen all black. PLEASE ADVICE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You need to learn patience.  It can sometimes take HOURS before you get a response, you've only had this post for 37 minutes, and are checking every 10 - 20 minutes, you need to WAIT A WHILE, at least a few days, before you can say that there's no activity or no response...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a memory issue. You must have run out of memory and hence the reason Ubuntu cannot continue installing because its getting chocked in the middle of the process. What error message are you getting?

Comment: I think we can close this now. Apologies for the impatience.I reinstalled ubuntu. Seemed like the best option.